# HTML5 datalist element in Opera

Tags: php, wordpress, html, opera, datalist

I'm trying to add a datalist in WordPress user profile page. This is the code:

```
<input type="text" list="my_list" name="my[artist]" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'my_artist', $user->ID ) ); ?>" />
<datalist id="my_list">
    <option value="ACDC">ACDC</option>
    <option value="Iron Maiden">Iron Maiden</option>
    <option value="Led Zeppelin">Led Zeppelin</option>
    <option value="Metallica">Metallica</option>
    <option value="Megadeth">Megadeth</option>
    <option value="Pantera">Pantera</option>
    <option value="Slayer">Slayer</option>
</datalist>
```

Anything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but Opera shows a white box where the elements of the list are available but not visible, as shown in the image:

[image: Datalist in Opera]

I can select the options, but they are not visible. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

datalist is a bit buggy according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist on Opera.

The bug listed there is not the one you mentioned, but i guess that if it is not fully supported there are some other unexpected behaviors...

You should check the [datalist-polyfill](https://github.com/thgreasi/datalist-polyfill) , it might solve your issue.